# Read last few lines of text file? c#

Tags: c#

First of all I'm not the most experienced person using c#, the only thing I've done so far is reading the entire text file.

I'd like to read the last few lines of a text file, I'll need to do this for several text files eventually and the format of each one is the same, there's roughly 80 odd lines of information that I'd like to leave out then when the word '#Footer' is reached, if possible, I'd like to read all the lines after that specific word (roughly I'll be keeping about 6/7 lines after the word '#Footer' for each text file).

Any ideas on how I'd go about this? Thanks

Comment: How big are these files?

Comment: If you want to search for some text - you have to read whole file anyway.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [File.ReadLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503.aspx) which doesn't require to load whole file to memory.

```
var lines = File.ReadLines(fname)
            .SkipWhile(line => !line.StartsWith("#Footer"))
            .Skip(1)
            .ToList();
```

**EDIT**

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, lines));
```

Comment: or `!line.Contains("#Footer")`

Comment: Thanks for that, but after writing everything and running it, in the command console it just says 'Press any key to continue...' Any clue on where I'm going wrong? Sorry about the lack of knowledge on my part :L

Comment: @user2948119 Nothing wrong, you just ran your program. What are you doing with `lines`? Have you tried to display it?

Comment: Oh right, how would I display the program in the command prompt then? (again, sorry for only knowing a limited amount)

Comment: ah thank you very much, I've got 1 error, "the name 'lines' does not exist in the current context", I may be missing something?

Comment: @user2948119 it is declared in `var lines = File.ReadLines(fname)....`, you shouldn't get it.(unless you put it in another method/class)

Comment: I have, var lines = File.ReadLines(@"my file location\testfile.datafile") in which the testfile.datafile is the text file im using, would that be correct?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645597(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
 private  String GetFooter(String filePath)
        {

            String inputText = "#Footer";
            String footerText ="";
            String [] allFileLines=(String[])File.ReadLines(filePath).ToArray();
            int footerLineNo = -1;
            for (int i = 0; i < allFileLines.Length; i++)
            {
                if (allFileLines[i].Contains(inputText))
                    footerLineNo = i;
            }

            if (footerLineNo > -1)
            {
                for (int i = footerLineNo + 1; i < allFileLines.Length; i++)
                    footerText += allFileLines[i]+"\n";
            }
            return footerText;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
        bool check= false;
        string myline;
        string mytext = "";
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("temp.txt");
        while ((myline= reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            if (myline.Contains("#Footer") || check)
            {
                check= true;
                mytext += line;
            }
        }
```